# Bring axes to front without redrawing the figure?

Tags: matlab, plot, multiple-axes

Is there a way in Matlab to bring an axes to front without having Matlab perform a redraw (`drawnow`) implicitly?

Background to my question:
I am preparing a large figure with several subplots. In some of them I have 2 axes superposed, because I want to see the same data on 2 different y-scales. 
After playing around with axes settings, I finally got the figure to look like I expected.

But: I need to bring one of the axes to front (in my case, the left axes hAxL). 
So I have this line in my code: `axes(hAxL);`
This works, but, it seems that Matlab not only brings the axes to front, but also redraws the figure.

That's a pity because I am preparing the entire figure with `'visible','off'` to accelerate it. The implicit `drawnow` blows my idea and makes the figure popup several times, which is annoying and takes the code longer to execute...

I have already tried this: `set(gcf ,'CurrentAxes',hAxL)`, but it only makes `hAxL` the current axes and does not bring it to front. 
Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe uistack could be a solution.

Try

```
uistack(hAxL, 'top')
```

Comment: works like a charm! I was no aware of uistack. This essentially halved my plotting time :-)   Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

This is also a pretty simple solution that should work for that situation.

```
set(hAxL ,'Layer', 'Top')
```

Comment: `uistack(hAxL, 'top')` did not work for me on MATLAB R2016b, but `set(hAxL ,'Layer', 'Top')` worked really well!

Comment: Or `set(gca, 'Layer', 'Top');` +1.